# ruby object to_s gives unexpected output

Tags: ruby, indicator

What is the correct way to view the output of the `puts` statements below? My apologies for such a simple question.... Im a little rusty on ruby. [github repo](https://github.com/Nedomas/indicators)

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'indicators'

my_data = Indicators::Data.new(Securities::Stock.new(:symbol => 'AAPL', :start_date => '2012-08-25', :end_date => '2012-08-30').output)

puts my_data.to_s #expected to see Open,High,Low,Close for AAPL
temp=my_data.calc(:type => :sma, :params => 3)

puts temp.to_s #expected to see an RSI value for each data point from the data above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.inspect` method instead of `.to_s` if you want to see internal properties of objects.

Comment: How would I access the attributes? for example if `temp.inspect` returns `#<Indicators::Main:0x00000002c76d50 @abbr="SMA", @params=3, @output=[nil, nil, 89.09592100000002, 88.57603566666667]>`

Comment: `puts temp@output` is not any kind of valid Ruby syntax. If `output` is a method on `temp`, use `temp.output`. If `output` is an instance variable, try `temp.instance_variable_get("@output")`

Comment: @maxpleaner thank you for the awesome answer and comment. I also found useful to use `temp.instance_variable_set(:@other, 'variable')` for adding more properties to order an array with these objects (`arr.sort_by { |ob| ob.instance_variable_get("@other") }`.

Comment: @CPHPython I was not the one who posted this answer, thanks anyway though

Answer (score 3):

Maybe check out the `awesome_print` gem.

It provides the `.ai` method which can be called on anything.

An example:

```
my_obj = { a: "b" }
my_obj_as_string = my_obj.ai
puts my_obj_as_string
# ... this will print
# {
#     :a => "b"
# }
# except the result is colored.
```

You can shorten all this into a single step with `ap(my_obj)`.

There's also a way to return objects as HTML. It's the `my_obj.ai(html: true)` option.